# Java Object Comparison by converting to JSON

Tags: java

Need to compare two big object with of same class type. Which has many properties including list of objects.

We were using Apache common's EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals to check equal, it is a quiet good library, but for sub arrays and sub-objects properties we need to look and check for equality. so we need to write a lot of code.

We were thinking about a different solution, to convert both object to JSON string and compare this JSON string using normal simple String comparison.

Will that make any performance issues in the System? Or do anyone have a better way to solve this?

Comment: Only YOU can decide if the performance is acceptable. There are so many variables here that nobody else can answer this question for you.

Comment: If order of arrays/collections is important json conversion and string comparison won't help. There are lot of open source libraries for this would recommend to give them a shot.

Answer (score 0):

conversion and comparison is a bad idea !!

there is a library available for this that is very simple and robust you can take a look for that 
[Javer object comparision](http://javers.org/documentation/getting-started/)